# Whitespace in statsd metric name

Tags: statsd

I need to pass whitespace as part of metric name when pushing data into a statsd collector. The specification doesn't mention if this is allowed, but inserting values with whitespace isn't working.

```
ref locale:23.5|g
```

https://github.com/b/statsd_spec

Is there a workaround such as special character escaping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where are you sending your statsd metrics to? Statsd might allow spaces in metric names, but I believe Graphite doesn't.

See https://answers.launchpad.net/graphite/+question/171766:

> These metrics are stored on disk as the name provided. It's a core
>   part of the current Whisper storage system.

And http://mingbowan.blogspot.com.es/2012/08/enable-special-character-support-in.html:

> Graphite doesn’t support special characters like “ “ (empty space),
>   “/” slash etc. Because it expect everything to be just ASCII to
>   split/processing them, and then make directories based on metric name.

I'm sorry I couldn't find an authoritative source.

I think your best bet would be to replace spaces in your metrics by some other character like "_".

Comment: I'll be replacing whitespace in metric names just to be safe. It seems to be a better choice to avoid compatibility issues in case I need to change persistence implementation down the road.